# Identifying Vent in Unfinished Basement & General Bathroom Layout

Tags: plumbing, basement, rough-in

I am looking to finish my basement and wanted to get validation on my vent tie-in locations.

I believe I have correctly identified it in the photo (*top right of photo*).
I believe the builders have it routed directly to a drain.

- I plan on reducing the 3" to use for my dual vanity, should i just replace this 3"?
- I added a vent for the toilet, can i just use the one from the sink?

Also, would appreciate any helpful thought on the layout below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That probably is a vent.  A good way to confirm is to buy a smoke candle and send smoke up the vent.  Have a shop vac or cylinder ventilator handy just in case, and get a helper to assist you.  One person needs to be outside watching to see if all the smoke comes out the roof penetration (it should.)  An alternative is to send some water down the vent from the roof and see if it comes out where you expect, but that isn't guaranteed to work; the vent could work properly but drain to somewhere else.